# Using instance variable of one sub class in to another sub class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, inheritance, instance-variables

I am creating a user class which has a first name and last name.

```
class User

  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name

end
```

Then, I created a teacher class to teach knowledge.

```
require_relative "./user.rb"

class Teacher < User

  attr_accessor :string1

  def initialize
    @string1 = string1
  end

  KNOWLEDGE = ["a String is a type of data in Ruby", "programming is hard, but it's worth it", "javascript async web request", "Ruby method call definition", "object oriented dog cat class instance", "class method class variable instance method instance variable", "programming computers hacking learning terminal", "bash Ruby rvm update certs"]


  def teach
    @string1 = KNOWLEDGE.sample
  end

end
```

Now, finally, I created student class to access functionality of user and teacher classes with some added functions.

```
require_relative "./user.rb"
require_relative "./teacher.rb"

class Student  < User

  attr_accessor :knowledge

  def initialize
    @knowledge = []
  end

  def learn(string1)
    @knowledge.push(@string1)
  end


end
```

What I would like Student class #learn to do is take the instance variable @string1 and push that to knowledge array. Somehow, it's not working as I tink it should.

Also, I have this bin file, where I have a student and a teacher. So, if I try to see knowledge array, It doesn't respond!

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require_relative "../lib/user.rb"
require_relative "../lib/teacher.rb"
require_relative "../lib/student.rb"

hima = Student.new
hima.first_name = "Hima"
hima.last_name = "Chhag"

pooja = User.new
pooja.first_name = "Pooja"
pooja.last_name = "Jeckson"

trushal = Teacher.new
trushal.first_name = "Trushal"
trushal.last_name = "Chitalia"


some_knowledge = trushal.teach

hima.learn(some_knowledge)

puts "Hima just learned this important knowledge: '#{hima.knowledge[0]}' from Trushal"

some_knowledge = trushal.teach

hima.learn(some_knowledge)

puts "Hima just learned this important knowledge: '#{hima.knowledge[1]}' from Trushal"

hima.knowledge
```

I will really appreciate if anyone can help me to find what's wrong with my code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing the instance variable `@string1` (evaluating to `nil`) instead of the parameter `string1`.

Try this:

```
def learn(string1)
  @knowledge.push(string1)
end
```

Also you seem to be trying to "share" an instance variable. But, by definition, an instance variable belongs to just one instance of an object. But that's not a problem - your `teach()` method already returns some knowledge, which you can then use in your `learn()` method.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, you are right. I was trying to share instance variable. But got your point. :-)